Cloud Run: Laravel Image Upload Works in Staging but Fails in Production Using Google Cloud Storag
I'm deploying a Laravel app on Cloud Run and using Google Cloud Storage (GCS) for uploading images. I'm using the spatie/laravel-google-cloud-storage package. The upload functionality works perfectly in my staging environment (a normal Server) but fails in production, even though the configuration and code are identical.
Here’s the code snippet I’m using for handling the image upload:


if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $imagePath = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'gcs');
    $validatedData['image'] = Storage::disk('gcs')->url($imagePath);
}



Additional Information:

The GCS bucket is set up with uniform bucket-level permissions.
The GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT, GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET, and other related environment variables are properly configured in both environments.
Service accounts for both environments have the same roles (roles/storage.objectAdmin and roles/storage.objectViewer).
Laravel filesystem configuration (config/filesystems.php) is identical between staging and production.
I'm not seeing any errors in the logs related to GCS or file uploads, but the image upload fails silently (or sometimes doesn't return the expected URL).

What I've Tried:

Verified that the production service account has sufficient permissions to access the GCS bucket.
Double-checked that the production environment is using the same .env configuration as staging.

Questions:

Could this issue be related to the way spatie/laravel-google-cloud-storage interacts with GCS in a production environment?
What debugging steps or configuration adjustments can I try to pinpoint the problem?

